# Sorting out strands in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of pairs of numbers with the list sorted by the number on the right- eg:

```
[(7, 1)
 (6, 2)
 (5, 3)
 (8, 5)
 (9, 7)
 (4, 9)]
```

and I want to get out the strands that are linked. A strand is defined as:

```
x->y->z
```

where tuples exist:

```
(y, x)
(z, y)
```

The strands in the above example are:

```
1->7->9->4
2->6
3->5->8
```

in the above example. I cannot think of any sensible code; as simple iteration with a counting variable will cause significant repeats. Please give me some pointers.

Comment: You need to build a map and write a pathing algorithm

Comment: Sorry, the format of my question has been lost - the list was meant to look like this (7 1), (6 2), (5, 3), (8 5), (9 7), (4 9); so since 1 joins to 7, and 7 pairs with 9, and 9 pairs with 4; they are a strand

Comment: The proper data structure here is called a linked-list

Comment: Thank you cricket - can now search for information regarding the correct thing

Comment: No problem. Some pointers would be to hold a list of linked-lists, then as you iterate over your numbers, you'll need to check which list contains the correct number, then link them appropriately when you find a match.

Answer (score 1):

There's an easier way to do this than a real linked list. Since there's no real need for traversal, you can simply build regular lists as you go.

```
ts = [(7, 1),
      (6, 2),
      (5, 3),
      (8, 5),
      (9, 7),
      (4, 9)]

def get_strands(tuples):
    '''builds a list of lists of connected x,y tuples

    get_strands([(2,1), (3,2), (4,3)]) -> [[1,2,3,4]]

    Note that this will not handle forked or merging lists intelligently
    '''
    lst = []
    for end, start in tuples:
        strand = next((strand for strand in lst if strand[-1]==start), None)
        # give me the sublist that ends with `start`, or None
        if strand is None:
            lst.append([start, end])  # start a new strand
        else:
            strand.append(end)
    return lst
```

Demo:

```
In [21]: get_strands(ts)
Out[21]: [[1, 7, 9, 4], [2, 6], [3, 5, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most complete solution is to create a graph from your data and then perform a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) on it. It will provide your expected result as long as the your graph doesn't have any cycles.